# OpenCL CVMS_ERROR_SERVICE_FAILURE: CVMS compiler has crashed or hung managing the service?

Tags: c, opencl

i have this output from the compiler with clGetProgramBuildInfo from this kernel:

CVMS_ERROR_SERVICE_FAILURE: CVMS compiler has crashed or hung managing the service

```
__kernel void vadd(
__global char* char_array,
int m,
int n,
__global long* result)
{

int index = get_global_id(0);
int max_n = n/m;
if(index == m-1){
    max_n = n - (n/m)*(m-1);
}

long max[ max_n ];
int offset = log2((double)m);

for (int it=0; it < max_n; it++)
{
    __global char* bits = &(char_array[64*(n/m)*(index-1)+it*64]);
    int count=0;
    for(int i=offset; i<=64; i++)
    {
        if(bits[i]=='0'){
            count++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    max[it] = count;
}

*result = 0;
long tmp = 0;
for(int i=0; i<max_n;i++)
{
    if(max[i] > *result){*result = max[i];}
}
*result = tmp +1;
}
```

i get this output changing the line "int offset = log2(m);" in "int offset = log2((double)m);" before the compiler log the the call to log2(m) was ambiguous how can i call log2 properly? Thanks

Comment: It's a little unclear the way you wrote it what order you did things in, and exactly what the error was each time. Did you get a compile time error, fix it and then get a runtime error possibly related to something else? Any error text to show us? In the industry usually code syntax has a space around operators  `*`. For your own sake and to avoid frustration of reviewers who work with pro code, consider looking on net and github for code examples from 'real life". Try "64 * (n / m) * (index - 1) + it * 64"  In the long run you'll realize it's easier to read and looks less cramped and cryptic.