# log2 function in OpenCL kernel?

Tags: c, opencl

Hi i have a problem with the log2 function used in an OpenCL kernel, i have a compiler crash:

CVMS_ERROR_SERVICE_FAILURE: CVMS compiler has crashed or hung managing the service

the code is this:

int offset = log2((double)m)

where m is an int, where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: What value is `m`? Note that the logarithm of `m` with a value <= 0 is undefined. What crashed - the compiler or the executable code?

Comment: m value is 256, the compiler of the kernel, the log returned with clGetProgramBuildInfo is "CVMS_ERROR_SERVICE_FAILURE: CVMS compiler has crashed or hung managing the service"

Comment: You asked the same [more detailed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082588/opencl-cvms-error-service-failure-cvms-compiler-has-crashed-or-hung-managing-th) only recently.

Comment: i hope that wrote in this way it should be more clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCL CVMS\_ERROR\_SERVICE\_FAILURE: CVMS compiler has crashed or hung managing the service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082588/opencl-cvms-error-service-failure-cvms-compiler-has-crashed-or-hung-managing-th)

Comment: Does your OpenCL implementation support the `cl_khr_fp64` extension for double-precision arithmetic, and have you enabled it in your kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error, so I assume it's a driver issue.

According to the [OpenCL documentation](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-2-quick-reference-card.pdf), `T log2 (T)` is defined, so `log2(double)` returns a `double` which should only give you a compiler warning when implicitly casted to `int`. Try

```c
int offset = (int)(log2((float)m)+0.5f);
```

to avoid any compiler warning and if this still does not work, use my [evil fast log2 method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905558/9178992)

```c
int offset = (as_uint((float)m)>>23)-127;
```

which uses the built-in OpenCL function `as_uint(float)`.